# Capture the output of DOS (command prompt) and display in a JAVA Frame

Tags: java, capture

When I run a python script, the output appears on the DOS ( command prompt in Windows ).

I want the output be displayed on a JAVA Application, i.e. on a window which contians JTextArea. The output should be same as that on the DOS.

So, **How do I capture the output from the DOS and insert it into JAVA Application ??**

(I tried storing output of the python script in a text file and then reading it using JAVA. But, in that case, the JAVA application waits for the script to finish running first and then displays the output. And, when the output is more than the screen size, a scroll bar appeears, so that I can see the entire output.)

---

After crowder's comment, I ran this code. but the output is always:

error:
Process said:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
class useGobbler {
        public static void main ( String args[] )
        {
        ProcessBuilder pb; 
        Process p;
        Reader r;
        StringBuilder sb;
        int ch;

        sb = new StringBuilder(2000);

        try
        {
            pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","printHello.py");
            p = pb.start();

            r = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
            while((ch =r.read() ) != -1)
            {
                sb.append((char)ch);
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("error");

        }

        System.out.println("Process said:" + sb);
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ??

Comment: Re your update (which is really a completely different question): **Whare are the details of the exception?** That's kind of important. :-) It will have useful information on it, telling you why an `IOException` has occurred. At a *guess*, I'd say either `python` is not in your path, or `preintHello.py` is not in the current directory.

Comment: The file is in the same directory. The absolute address is C:\Users\parth.k\Documents\printHello.py     As far as 'python' is concerned, when I type 'python' in my command prompt, it gives an error saying that "it is not recognized as an internal or external command..."   And, do you mean to say that if I print the details of the exception, we will be able to figure out the exact reason ?? In that case, I will print that and get back to you.

Comment: @ user: Yes, I mean that if you output the text of the exception, it will tell you what's wrong. But in your case, you already know: *"...is not recognized as an internal or external command"* So `python` isn't in your path and Java can't run it. That error message sounds like Windows, so this page should be helpful: http://docs.python.org/faq/windows.html#how-do-i-run-a-python-program-under-windows This part of things has nothing to do with Java or your original question.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute the process via a [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), which will give you a [`Process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) instance on which you can read the output via the stream returned from [`getInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29).

Here's an example that runs the Python script `hello.py` and builds up its output in a string:

```
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class RunPython {
    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder  pb;
        Process         p;
        Reader          r;
        StringBuilder   sb;
        int             ch;

        // Start the process, build up its output in a string
        sb = new StringBuilder(2000);
        try {
            // Create the process and start it
            pb = new ProcessBuilder("python", "hello.py");
            p = pb.start();

            // Get access to its output
            r = new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());

            // Read until we run out of output
            while ((ch = r.read()) != -1) {
                sb.append((char)ch);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            // Handle the I/O exception appropriately.
            // Here I just dump it out, which is not appropriate
            // for real apps.
            System.err.println("Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        // Do what you want with the string; in this case, I'll output
        // it to stdout
        System.out.println("Process said: " + sb);
    }
}
```

You can then do whatever you like with the string, including putting it in the `JTextArea` like any other string. (You could use a `BufferedReader` around the `InputStreamReader` if you like, but you get the idea.)

Comment: I see that "just" growing into OP's biggest problem :) He needs a SwingWorker/invokeLater, which usually dumbfounds newbies.

Comment: @user1414696: I've updated with a better example for your situation; the example from the docs involving redirection and such had a low signal:noise ratio for your purposes. :-) Note Marko's point about thread interaction if you're trying to do interim updates and such.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Not necessarily, it depends on how long the process runs and whether the OP wants to do interim updates.

Comment: Good point. If it's only a split-second python script with a few lines of output, the GUI can block while it's running.

Comment: This appears far simpler to understand. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the error and inputStream, while Using `Runtime.exec()` oder `ProcessBuilder`.

Examples can be found here:
http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html