# capture output from c++ in java without returning

Tags: java, c++, swing, user-interface

i'm working on java SWING to make GUI for c++ programming . i need the c++ program to be executed in a loop without returning to the java. During this loop i want to capture some output without stepping through 
return 0; in c++ program

can i capture output from the c++ file without returning to the java GUI ??
this is my out and in process in my code

```
 try {
                int out = 0;
                String line;
                OutputStream stdin = null;
                InputStream stderr = null;
                InputStream stdout = null;

                // calling the exe file
                Process process = new ProcessBuilder("unpattern.exe").start();
                stdin = process.getOutputStream();
                stderr = process.getErrorStream();
                stdout = process.getInputStream();

                // input process
                // "write" the parms into stdin
                line = "1";
                stdin.write(line.getBytes());
                stdin.flush();

                //line = "tx.getText()" + "\n";
                // stdin.write(line.getBytes());
               // stdin.flush();

                stdin.close();
                 // output process
                // clean up if any output in stdout
                BufferedReader brCleanUp =
                        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

                while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null) {
                    // counter of the defects
                    System.out.println(line);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(QeyeGui3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i could to find a suitable solution for my problem in this link
[Capture the output of DOS (command prompt) and display in a JAVA Frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10735619/capture-the-output-of-dos-command-prompt-and-display-in-a-java-frame)
i added the buffer in string builder so i could make it :)
thank you for every help :)

Answer (score 4):

Your while loop is missing its closing brace:

```
            // ....
            while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null) {
                // counter of the defects
                System.out.println(line);
            // **** it should go here
        }
```

I suggest you continuously get the text that is passed into the BufferedReader in your while loop. If you are doing this within a Swing application's SwingWorker, then you could use the publish/process method pair to update the Swing GUI with the information that is transmitted.

Comment: but even after making the BufferedReader inside the loop, the gui in java still waiting the return command in c++  .... i don't use SwingWorker before is it will be useful for my case???

Comment: @sohasamy: don't *"make"* the BufferedReader inside of the loop, but certainly read from it inside the loop. And of course you'll need a background thread else Swing will freeze. The easiest and safest way to do this is with a SwingWorker.

Comment: i could to find a suitable solution for my problem in this link Capture the output of DOS (command prompt) and display in a JAVA Frame i added the buffer in string builder so i could make it :) thank you for every help :)